# Vue property is not defined on instance but referenced on render

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to create a page specific Vue Instance for a form in my Application, but I keep getting the following error and the message isn't rendered:

```
_[Vue warn]: Property or method "message" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option.(found in Root)_
```

I am using Laravel 5.4's default app.js Entry Point, with one custom component loaded.

App.JS:

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

window.events = new Vue();
window.notify = function(message,type){
    window.events.$emit('notify',message,type);
};

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

Vue.component('notification', require('./components/Notification.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
   el: '#app'
});
```

Page-Specific Vue Istance:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        new Vue({
           el: '#createPlanForm',

            created: function(){
               console.log("Test");
            },
            data: {
               message: 'Test'
            }
        });
    </script>
```

The form does have the correct ID set, and I can see the Console Logged test message, as well.

Form Template:

```
{{ Form::open(['id' => 'createPlanForm','route' => 'ops.plans.store','class' => 'form-horizontal']) }}

                <div class="form-group @if($errors->has("name")) has-error @endif">
                  <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name:</label>

                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    {{ Form::text('name',null,['class' => 'form-control']) }}

                    @if($errors->has('name'))<span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('name') }}</span> @endif
                  </div>
                </div>
            @{{ message }}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-flat btn-block btn-default">Create Plan</button>
                </div>
            {{ Form::close() }}
```

Comment: I don't know if this is the warning cause, but it might be a component problem. When defining components, the data needs to be created as a callback that returns an object, not as an object.

Comment: @void That is the way the data is declared in my component, actually. And the component itself appears to work fine. Anyway, thank you for the response!

Comment: What's the template for createPlanForm?

Comment: @BertEvans Must have forgot to include that.. I've added it to the bottom of the post.

Comment: Is it possible `createPlanForm` is nested inside `app`? I expect that would cause the issue.

Comment: @BertEvans It's possible. Although, I have the same issue if I remove the Global Vue Reference as well. In any case, What would you suggest? I don't want to rewrite the whole form as a component, because of the heavy usage of blade within the template.

Comment: If it's not nested, I don't see an obvious problem. Can you show the rendered HTML (view source on the page). Possibly some hint there.

Comment: Hm. I'm not sure how to explain this... no further alterations to the code, it just kinda started working. Some weird bug I suppose. Thanks for the help, anyways!

Comment: Gotta love those :) Good luck!